# How to say "we thought about" in an academic way?

Tags: word-choice, academia

In the following sentence:

> Since there are many row values at each step of the process, one approach we thought about is to aggregate all the row values into a single value

What is the alternative of one “we thought about” in academic writing?

Comment: I think I can offer a solution to your underlying problem but it has little to do with the English language (and thus does not fit here, but rather on [acdemia.se] or [writing.se]) and I can be more specific when you provide more context: What happened to your thoughts? Why do you mention them to begin with?

Comment: 'Considered' is doubtless easily found by simple research, and is an ELL level answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since there are many row values at each step of the process, one approach we **considered** was to aggregate all the row values into a single value

Since there are many row values at each step of the process, one approach we **contemplated** was to aggregate all the row values into a single value

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/consider

examined or scrutinised would also work.

Comment: +1 for  "considered". I think that is the idiomatic option.

Answer (score 4):

Some other options
Since there are many row values at each step of the process, one approach we **evaluated** was to aggregate all the row values into a single value.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/evaluate?s=t

Assessed and surveyed would also work

Comment: Although the thesaurus may list these words as synonyms, it does not mean that they are exactly equivalent in all instances.  Here, I would suggest that "considered" and "contemplated" are equivalent to one another and to op's phrase “we thought about”.  But, to me, "evaluated" implies a bit more than mere consideration: it implies that we actually studied it in more detail, maybe even carried out a few tests (depending on what "it" actually is). Hence, I **don't** think that "evaluated" is an appropriate replacement for "we thought about".

Comment: True, "evaluated" is different than "considered" for the reasons you listed. I was not simply offering synonyms but possible interpretations of "thought about". In looking at the context of the sentence "aggregate all the row values into a single value" was a detailed solution that may have been more than considered but actually evaluated or assessed.

Answer (score -2):

In your sentence, all the following verbs and phrasal verbs will make sense:

1. Contemplate
2. Mull over
3. Chew over
4. Deliberate

Comment: Please do not include generic website 'recommendations' and other superfluous comments in your answers.  I have amended your answer to remove those.

Comment: "Chew over" is not academic or formal. "Mull over" doesn't sound quite right for the context either; it is more used for moral dilemmas or similar tricky decisions, than scientific investigations involving practical examination and research.